# Issue Reading Certain Excel Files from Database using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a Python function that retrieves file content from a database and attempts to read it using the pandas library. While this function successfully reads some files, it fails for others, specifically some Excel files.

The function uses pd.read_excel for files with .xls or .xlsx extensions and pd.read_csv for .csv files. I've confirmed that the failing files open correctly in Excel and also can be read using Pandas in a different environment. However, in the main environment where this function runs, there's an issue.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
if file_record.filename.endswith(".csv"):
    data = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(file_record.content))
elif file_record.filename.endswith((".xls", ".xlsx")):
    data = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(file_record.content))
else:
    raise ValueError("Unsupported file format")
```

When I try to read the Costco Excel file (.xlsx) and one other file (The files are correct and not corrupted), it fails on the pd.read_excel line, but other files like Walmart and Amazon read just fine.

Additionally, when debugging:

The line print("This is the file record", file_record.content) correctly prints the file content.
However, the subsequent line print("This is the data", data) prints empty data, indicating the reading process didn't work as expected.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or had suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this problem?